# Error while compiling WebStorm Node.js project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, webstorm

I just created a simple project in WebStorm using `Express module`
then I install `mongoose` and after that I have tried to connect to MongoDB, but it's giving this exception:

**Index.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('localhost', 'Test');
var schema = mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string' },{age:'int'});
var Human = mongoose.model('Human', schema);

 exports.saveHuman = function (req,res){
"use strict";
var Ahs = new Human({name:'Dumy'},{age:24});
Ahs.save(function(error , data ){

    if(error){
        console.log("Not working");
    }
    else{
        res.send(Ahs.name + "Created !");
    }

});
};

 exports.index = function(req, res){
 "use strict";
res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
 };
```

**app.js**

```
var express, routes, user, http, path;
express = require('express');
routes = require('./routes');
user = require('./routes/user');
http = require('http');
path = require('path');

var app = express();

 app.configure(function(){
"use strict";
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
"use strict";
app.use(express.errorHandler());
 });
app.get('/saveHuman',routes.saveHuman);
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
"use strict";
console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
 });
```

Now, when I run the project it shows this in console .

[image]

Comment: Do you have a fully up-to-date version of express? That code looks fine to me. The error looks like it is coming from your `.get('port')` line, but that should work.

Comment: In the future, please paste the actual text of your error. Not only is it really hard to read as an image, but now people with the same problem won't be able to search for it.